# RSA cross platform b/w JAVA & Symbian

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, symbian

1) I am able to Encrypt and Decrypt with my app generated values in symbian with the below values

```
          RInteger iE = RInteger::NewL(0x10001);            
          RInteger iN = RInteger::NewL(_L8("\xa3\x92\xb7\x34\x82\xbe\x7f\x4f\x8f\xbd\xfb\xd4\xf9\x80\x76\xe0\xa3\xf7\x42\x60\x8e\xe2\xa8\x6b\x76\x22\x67\x0e\x94\xeb\x9b\x3f\xd0\x73\x58\xe0\x23\xbb\x25\x53\x82\x56\x7b\x3e\x05\x57\xc9\x50\x3c\x2d\x6a\x09\x66\x3f\x49\xee\x41\x4c\x4b\x95\x1e\x7d\xb8\xd1\xc5\x40\x0d\xd0\xca\x72\xc8\xf6\x0d\x21\x4f\x63\xc1\x4c\x3b\x93\x94\x1f\x67\x5b\x70\x33\x07\xfd\x4e\x71\x59\x7f\x79\x9b\xd8\xf6\x3b\x35\xe1\x9a\xd3\x27\x43\xdb\x32\xcd\x7b\x78\x40\xd1\x0d\x40\x12\x53\xb7\x19\x66\xca\x5b\xf6\x26\x2a\xea\x4e\xef\xe4\xc8\x41"));
          RInteger iD = RInteger::NewL(_L8("\x44\x21\x5a\xff\x9b\x29\x7f\x5b\x83\x32\x8d\x8f\x02\xb1\x18\x52\xae\xd8\xd1\x23\xe8\xbf\xcd\x88\x9c\xf6\xed\x57\xec\x7d\x49\xf7\xc5\x7a\x15\xdd\x9d\xe4\x58\x42\xb5\x3a\x12\x31\x1e\x06\x97\x8a\x3c\xd6\x69\xa1\x2a\x9e\x57\xcb\xce\x14\xda\x32\x6d\x35\xce\x61\x9e\xb2\xaf\x5c\x04\x13\xef\x68\x43\x7e\xe4\x98\xdc\x87\x2e\x7e\x38\x5f\xbd\xe9\x2e\xc1\xf1\x94\xf3\x95\x56\x56\xa4\x78\x26\x70\xa4\x1e\x10\x61\xe9\x45\x25\x1c\xed\xc6\xc0\x1e\xf6\x2c\xa0\x27\xee\x19\x0a\xed\x1c\x76\x33\xc8\x37\xde\x76\x25\x1c\x70\x77\xb1"));
```

2)Receiving N,E & D values from server then generating Public & Private keys .
(a) Encrypting with public key in app and decrypting in server side successfully.
but
(b) not able to decrypt with private key in my app getting KErrInvalidPadding.
(c) Even with server encrypted message not able to decrypt in app getting same error KErrInvalidPadding.

code:

```
        RInteger iE = RInteger::NewL(0x10001);          
        RInteger iN = RInteger::NewL(_L8("\x89\x03\xfb\x6d\x15\xf3\x52\xed\x3b\x45\xad\xd3\x21\x6f\x63\x2f\x71\x39\x95\x4a\x56\x31\x33\x7a\xba\x7d\x64\x5e\xd3\x84\x82\xe3\xa8\x10\xb4\xdb\x26\xaa\xb4\xd1\xdf\x58\xc1\x47\x23\x0f\x0c\x75\x63\x1a\x3d\xd0\x55\x4b\x50\xde\x44\xe7\x9f\x4f\xcf\x20\x5c\x89\xfd\x3f\x80\xe0\xff\x8d\x16\xc2\xe9\xf5\x6e\xd3\xab\x17\x79\x53\xd5\x4c\x9c\x30\x35\x7d\x04\xe6\x77\xce\xdd\x99\x12\x90\x6e\xf8\xa0\x46\xd7\xb0\x18\x5b\x7f\x20\x22\xa8\xe4\x35\xb0\xc6\xec\xae\xf9\x3f\x08\x9f\xc3\xaa\x3f\x36\x77\x55\x0b\x5d\x84\x20\x46\xc7"));
        RInteger iD = RInteger::NewL(_L8("\x35\xb9\x42\xff\x9d\xe8\xbf\xae\x57\x5c\x55\xf1\x00\x1e\x2d\xd4\xef\x5f\x75\xc3\x25\x12\xbb\xad\xb6\xab\xee\x0c\x24\x81\xc3\xd4\xc2\x14\x72\xe5\xaf\x3e\xa6\x11\xd8\xb2\x73\x6e\x92\x37\x97\x59\xfb\xd6\xd1\x3f\xfc\x01\xc1\x1e\xb6\x03\xdf\xfa\xaa\x2b\x75\x3c\xed\xc6\x8a\x02\x58\xb6\x8d\x6d\xf8\x34\x65\x03\xe3\x8a\x15\x37\xdf\x12\xa8\x18\xff\xce\xfa\x20\x20\xd6\xb7\x1a\x05\x6f\x2c\x04\x13\x58\x62\x94\xe9\xbc\x63\xc8\xd3\xd6\x06\x61\x44\x3e\xac\xe4\x98\x14\x63\xb1\xf7\x06\xaf\x1c\x16\xb6\x5b\x87\x87\x8e\x26\x01"));          

        TBuf8 <1024>aaaa;
        TBuf8 <1024>aOut;

        CRSAPublicKey *iPubKey = CRSAPublicKey::NewL(iN,iE);  
        CRSAPrivateKey *iPriKey = CRSAPrivateKeyStandard::NewL(iN,iD);
        CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor *iEncr = CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor::NewL(*iPubKey);
        CRSAPKCS1v15Decryptor *iDecry = CRSAPKCS1v15Decryptor::NewL(*iPriKey);

        TRAPD(err3,iEncr->EncryptL(_L8("Hi"),aaaa)); 
        TRAPD(err2,iDecry->DecryptL(aaaa,aOut));   <-KErrInvalidPadding = -11003;
```

how to solve this issue anybody suggest me with this.

Comment: No comments??  suggestions!!??

Comment: These functions perform on "raw" keys, while signing with OpenSSL and the certificate file involves some padding of the input data, that is not implemented correctly under Symbian. This link might give you some hint: http://jonmccune.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/symbian-os-v91-c-cryptography-apis-available/

Comment: thank you but that's about verifier and signer and i dint got how to solve KErrInvalidPadding? any one can help me??

Comment: Did you try applying `CPaddingPKCS1Encryption::PadL` and `UnPadL` to your plaintext before and after the encryption respectively?

Comment: No i dint do pad and UnPad how to Pad and UnPad? and In RSAEncryption method only PKCS15V padding is there right so apart from that i have to do Pad and UnPad separately??

Comment: It does indeed PKCS15V padding. What about usage, check out the ref at http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/GUID-E35887BB-7E58-438C-AA27-97B2CDE7E069/GUID-251A35C1-CC66-4DE4-9EBE-964026E89E7F/GUID-3150ECC9-CF8E-3890-91CD-87F5EBCE550E.html. I am not sure it'll work but it might worth a try.

Comment: if i do padding and send that data to Encrypt method then i'll get CRYPTO-LIB 3 panic. code:  TBuf8 <128>xyz;
            CPadding* padding = CPaddingPKCS1Encryption::NewL(128);    
          CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor *iEncr = CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor::NewL(*iPubKey);
           padding->PadL(_L8("welcome"),xyz);iEncr->EncryptL(xyz,aaaa)

Comment: still i am not able to solve -11003(KErrInvalidPadding) error.anybody have idea about this??

Answer (score 0):

what do i do

```
TInt len=iEncr->MaxOutputLength();
iEncr->EncryptL(_L8("Hi"),aaaa);
if (aaaa.Length()<len){
    TBuf8<1> t;
    t.SetLength(1);t[0]=0;
    aaaa.Insert(0,t);
}
```